# Json как парсить на Java?

Tags: java, json, синтаксический-анализ, json-encode

Здравствуйте!
Есть вот такой ответ от сервера:

```
 {
    "p_result": "ok",
    "p_item": [
        {
            "p_id": 132,
            "p_name": "Николай"
        }, 
        {
            "p_id": 133,
            "p_name": "Светлана"
        }
    ]
 }
```

Если правильно понимаю, то это массив.
Нужно написать метод который будет по параметру находить нужный элемент
что то наподобие :

```
_http.getArrayParamValue("p_name");
```

Никак не могу сообразить.

p.s. думаю для меня было бы полезнее некое указание, нежели ссылка на очерендую библиотеку. Спасибо!

**Решение.** Ошибку тоже понял. @Josfey Спасибо огромное. Вы очень мне помогли!

```
String str = null; 
String input = "данные полученные от сервера"; 

JsonParser parser = new JsonParser(); 
JsonObject mainObject = parser.parse(input).getAsJsonObject();
JsonArray pItem = mainObject.getAsJsonArray("p_item"); 

for (JsonElement user : pItem) {

    JsonObject userObject = user.getAsJsonObject(); 
    userObject.get("p_id"); 
    str = userObject.get("p_id").toString(); 
}
```

Comment: [Работа с JSON в Java][1]


  [1]: http://goloburdin.blogspot.ru/2011/03/json-java.html

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что вы хотите извлечь из вашей структуры? Имя пользователя по его `p_id`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Не совсем понял, что именно вы хотите извлечь из приведённой json-структуры, но вот, например, как извлечь из неё имя пользователя c id = 132 с помощью [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson).

```
String input = "тут ваша json-структура";
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject mainObject = parser.parse().getAsJsonObject();
JsonArray pItem = mainObject.getAsJsonArray("p_item");
for (JsonElement user : pItem) {
    JsonObject userObject = user.getAsJsonObject();
    if (userObject.get("p_id").getAsInt() == 132) {
        System.out.println(userObject.get("p_name"));
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Решение. Ошибку тоже понял. Спасибо огромное. Вы очень мне помогли!


    String str=null;        
                String input = "данные из 1 поста";
                JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
                JsonObject mainObject = parser.parse(input).getAsJsonObject();
    
                JsonArray pItem = mainObject.getAsJsonArray("p_item");
                for (JsonElement user : pItem) {
                    JsonObject userObject = user.getAsJsonObject();
    
                    userObject.get("p_id");
    
                    str = userObject.get("p_id").toString();

Answer (score 7):

На мой взгляд, самая лучшая на данный момент библиотека для работы с JSON - это [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome) от fasterxml.

Измерял скорость сериализации/десериализации с помощью JMH, и эта библиотека показала наилучшие результаты на довольно сложной структуре данных. Кроме того, она имеет довольно богатый набор настроек: интернирование ключей, реакция на ошибки синтаксиса и т.п.

Если вы хотите не просто сериализовывать/десериализовывать JSON-документы, а хотите менять структуру JSON-документа на лету, то рекомендую [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

Answer (score 2):

Рекомендую обратить внимание на [json-simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/)
Вот [тут](http://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/) пример использования

Comment: Вот как раз ей и пользуюсь

Comment: но не получается

Comment: Начну все же задавтаь вопросы. Я понимаю так, что когда приходит JSON в таком виде

        {"p_result":"error, нет совпадений кода смс ","p_guid":""}
То это строка, соответственно результат этого запроса я могу поместить в переменную строкового типа?


Если приходит ответ, такой как в первом сообщений то это массив. И записывать надо в массив string[] myMas;
Так?

Comment: Есть код, который работает, только когда приходит ответ от сервара стокой JSON

        Есть у меня такой код: 
//Получим значение парметра по его имени
 public String getParamValue(String Name)
 {
  String Ret = null;
  try {
   Ret = (_J_result.getString(Name));
  } catch (JSONException e) {
   Ret = null;
  }
  
  return Ret;
  
 }

Comment: Когда ответ приходит в виде массива, пользуясь этим методом я получаю null