# Как правильно Json-ответ преобразовать в массив в Android приложении?

Tags: php, java, android, json

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    // Будет хранить параметры
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();
            // получаем JSON строк с URL
    JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest("тут ссылка на сайт", "GET", params);



    try {

            // Получаем масив из Продуктов
            dolzno = json.getJSONArray("dolzno");


            // перебор всех продуктов
            for (int i = 0; i < dolzno.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = dolzno.getJSONObject(i);

                // Сохраняем каждый json елемент в переменную
                String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);


                // Создаем новый HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // добавляем каждый елемент в HashMap ключ => значение
                map.put(TAG_ID, id);


                // добавляем HashList в ArrayList
                productsList.add(map);
            }



    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Сам `json`-ответ корректен вроде:

> {"dolzno":[{"_id":"1"},{"_id":"2"},{"_id":"4"}],"spec":[{"_id":"1"},{"_id":"2"},{"_id":"3"}],"otdel":[{"_id":"1"},{"_id":"2"},{"_id":"3"}]}

Он получается с url.

Насколько я понимаю, он содержит 3 объекта - `dolzno`, `otdel`, `spec`. Вот я и хочу каждый из этих обьектов запихать в `arraylist`. Однако программа почему-то не видит эти обьекты. (Ввожу их по названию, в примере `dolzno` - название первого обьекта)

После преобразования я планировал `arraylist` привязать к спиннеру.
В чем ошибаюсь?НИже код php

```
<?php
$res = array();
$response = array();
$response1 = array();
$response2 = array();

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// get all products from products table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dolz");
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM otdel");
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM spec");

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 and mysql_num_rows($result1) > 0) {
$response["dolzno"] = array();
$response1["otdel"] = array();
$response2["spec"] = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$product = array();
$product["_id"] = $row["_id"];

array_push($response["dolzno"], $product);
$res=array_merge((array)$res, (array)$response);
}
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
$product2 = array();
$product2["_id"] = $row["_id"];

array_push($response2["spec"], $product2);
$res=array_merge((array)$res, (array)$response2);
}
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
$product1 = array();
$product1["_id"] = $row["_id"];

array_push($response1["otdel"], $product1);
$res=array_merge((array)$res, (array)$response1);
}

echo json_encode($res);

} else {
$response1["success"] = 0;
$response1["message"] = "No products found";

echo json_encode($response1);
}

?>
```

Comment: Очень простой пример http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/312660/json-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-java

Comment: HashMap в цикле явно лишний, загоняйте строки прямо в productsList, а в остальном все Ок. В чем собственно проблема-то?

Comment: Программа не видит вообще json

Answer (score 1):

В общем, проблема была  на стороне php кода. Решается все (хотя я сам не понимаю почему) добавлением незначительного кода. Ниже рабочий код:

```
<?php
$res = array();
$response = array();
$response1 = array();
$response2 = array();



// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// get all products from products table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dolz");
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM otdel");
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM spec");

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 and mysql_num_rows($result1) > 0) {
    $response["dolzno"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $product = array();
        $product["_id"] = $row["_id"];


        array_push($response["dolzno"], $product);

        $res=array_merge((array)$res, (array)$response);

    }

    $response1["otdel"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
        $product1 = array();
        $product1["_id"] = $row["_id"];


        array_push($response1["otdel"], $product1);

        $res=array_merge((array)$res, (array)$response1);

    }
    $response2["spec"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
        $product2 = array();
        $product2["_id"] = $row["_id"];


        array_push($response2["spec"], $product2);

        $res=array_merge((array)$res, (array)$response2);

    }
 $res["success"] = 1;  
 echo json_encode($res);

} else {
    $res["success"] = 0;
    $res["message"] = "No products found";

    echo json_encode($res);
}


?>
```