# Не удаляется подстрока

Tags: java, android

У меня есть строка:

```
`{"response":{"count":544271,"items":[358322758,358306517,358297876,358293716,358293542,358285919,358281793,358241319,358239216,358238181]}}`
```

Я пытаюсь удалить ее первую часть, методом замены:

```
badString.replace("{\"response\":{\"count\":", "aaa");
```

Но, в результате, строка не изменяется, я получаю исходную строку! Почему так происходит и как это исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод `replace` возвращает изменённую строку, а не изменяет её. Засим вам надо присвоить результат вызова этого метода вашей строке.

```
badString = badString.replace("{\"response\":{\"count\":", "aaa");
```

В доках это тоже написано:

> Returns a copy of this string after replacing occurrences of target replaced with replacement.

Comment: ... а также впредь применять парсер JSON для разбора JSON :)

Comment: @VladD, полезное дополнение, да)

Comment: @VladD, хм.... а такое есть?)

Comment: @bukashka101, да, есть. Вот [пример](http://androiddocs.ru/parsing-json-poluchaem-i-razbiraem-json-s-vneshnego-resursa/)

Comment: @bukashka101: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/312660/10105