# Распарсить Json библиотекой GSON (Java)

Tags: java, json, gson

Коллеги не могу понять как распарсить вот такой вот запрос:

```
{
    "result":0,
    "message":"Success",
    "serial":2,
    "type":"callback",
    "data": {
        "terminals":
            [
                {
                    "id":46,
                    "name":"B2.0",
                    "login":null,
                    "is_free":true,
                    "client_params":{
                        "video_camera_host":"videoslots.live",
                        "video_camera_port":"1001"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id":48,
                    "name":"B2.0",
                    "login":null,
                    "is_free":true,
                    "client_params":{
                        "video_camera_host":null,
                        "video_camera_port":null
                    }
                }
            ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Я сам хочу в этом разбраться, вот посмотри это, может поможет: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/312660/json-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Описываете структуру вашего JSON в виде классов:

```
public class Response {
    public int result;
    public String message;
    public long serial;
    public String type;
    public Data data;
}

public class Data {
    public List<Terminal> terminals;
}

public class Terminal {
    public long id;
    public String name;
    public String login;
    public boolean isFree;
    public ClientParams clientParams;
}
public class ClientParams {
    public String videoCameraHost;
    public int videoCameraPort;
}
```

После чего скармливаете вашу строку с JSON в gson, не забыв включить поддержку `snake_case` в именах полей:

```
    Response response = new GsonBuilder()
            .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
            .create()
            .fromJson(json, Response.class);
```