# Преобразовать json в java класс

Tags: java, gson

Как мне преобразовать такой вот `json` в `Java` класс с помощью `GSON` ?

```
{ "type": "success", "value": { "id": 61, "joke": "Chuck Norris once ate a whole cake before his friends could tell him there was a stripper in it.", "categories": [] } }
```

Как будет выглядеть этот класс ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вообще для этого надо создать класс, куда будут выгружаться поля. Поля должны быть публичными и класс должен содержать пустой конструктор.

```
public class MyClass {

    public String joke;
    public int id;
    public String[] categories; 

    // Конструктор
    public MyClass(){

    }
}
```

далее просто выгружается в него из `json`

```
String jsonText = "{ \"id\": 61, \"joke\": \"Chuck Norris once ate a whole cake before his friends could tell him there was a stripper in it.\", \"categories\": [] }";

GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
Gson gson = builder.create();
MyClass myClass = gson.fromJson(jsonText, MyClass.class);
System.out.println("GSON", "id: " + myClass.id + "\njoke: " + myClass.joke);
```

---

Не помню можно ли можно через GSON взять сразу объект `value` из строки, которая у вас имеется (вроде бы можно [судя по информации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/313069/191482)), но определенно точно её можно достать другой библиотекой [org.json.java-json.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavajsonjar.htm)

будет это выглядеть примерно так:

```
import org.json.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception  {
        String json = "{ \"type\": \"success\", \"value\": { \"id\": 61, \"joke\": \"Chuck Norris once ate a whole cake before his friends could tell him there was a stripper in it.\", \"categories\": [] } }";
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONObject myClassJSONObject = obj.getJSONObject("value");
    }
}
```