# Как распаковать Ajax-запрос в Json , а с Jsona в Java?

Tags: java, ajax, json

```
var main = {
login: function () {
    var log = $("#log").val();
    var pass = $("#pass").val();
    var request = {};
    request.log = log;
    request.pass = pass;
    request.requestType = "login";
    $.ajax({ ///////////////////////
        type: "POST",
        url: "/api",
        dataType: "json",
        data: request,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response.key)
            document.location.href = "MainMenu.html";

        }
    }); ////////////////
}}
```

Создал вот такой Ajax запрос. Запрос отправляется на Сервлет. Вопрос: как принять, сохранить данные в переменные Javы и ответить?

Comment: Подробнее, что отвечает сервер? какие данные нужно сохранить и что нужно ответить?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Возможно поможет [этот](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/312660/json-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-java) вопрос

Comment: Отсылаю Ajax запрос на сервлет. Не приходит Suchess. Знаю что ajax нужно обработать внутри сервлета Jsoном, но не знаю как