# Как спарсить страны ВК?

Tags: java, android, json, vkontakte-api

Страны беру отсюда:

https://api.vk.com/api.php?oauth=1&method=database.getCountries&v=5.6&need_all=0&count=1000

```
{"response":
            {"count":18,
             "items":
                    [{"id":1,"title":"Россия"}]
            }
}
```

как парсить элементы `items`?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/312660/json-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Массив `items` можно получить следующим образом:

```
JSONObject response = new JSONObject(jsonStr).getJSONObject("response");
JSONArray items = response.getJSONArray("items");
```

, где `jsonStr` – Ваш JSON.

Далее можно получить список стран:

```
List<String> countriesArrayList = new ArrayList<>(items.length());

for (int i=0; i<items.length(); i++) {
    countriesArrayList.add(items.getJSONObject(i).getString("title"));
}
```