# парсить вложенные объекты JSON на java

Tags: java, json, объекты

Добрый день. Имеется ответ от сайта в формате JSON вида:

```
{
"name":"ivan"
"information":
 {
   "workName":
        {"name2":"prorab"},
   "adress":
        {"name2":"pastuh"},
 }
}
```

Как правильно доставать информацию из полей:
1 - workName, adress
2 - name2 
если количество объектов типа workName и adress постоянно меняется и меняются их названия. Получается что объект содержит в себе группу объектов?
Заранее спасибо.
P.s. форумы почитал, но толкового объяснения не увидел о вложенных объектах.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java и тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/312660/json-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-java

Comment: Создаейте объектную модель, описывающую эти данные и перегоняйте в JSON и обратно c [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson).

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/YhdRQAS.png