# Как распарсить json файл в android?

Tags: java, android, json

Пример кода из файла(сначала идет описание города, потом идет описание станций в этом городе):

```
{
  "citiesFrom" : [
    {
      "countryTitle" : "Австрия",
      "point" : {
        "longitude" : 16.36879539489746,
        "latitude" : 48.20253753662109
      },
      "districtTitle" : "",
      "cityId" : 2352,
      "cityTitle" : "Вена",
      "regionTitle" : "",
      "stations" : [
        {
          "countryTitle" : "Австрия",
          "point" : {
            "longitude" : 16.36879539489746,
            "latitude" : 48.20253753662109
          },
          "districtTitle" : "",
          "cityId" : 2352,
          "cityTitle" : "город Вена",
          "regionTitle" : "",
          "stationId" : 10154,
          "stationTitle" : "International Busterminal, Edbergstarsse 200 A"
        },
        {
          "countryTitle" : "Австрия",
          "point" : {
            "longitude" : 16.36879539489746,
            "latitude" : 48.20253753662109
          },
          "districtTitle" : "",
          "cityId" : 2352,
          "cityTitle" : "город Вена",
          "regionTitle" : "",
          "stationId" : 9864,
          "stationTitle" : "Stadion Center, Engerthstr. 242"
        },
        {
          "countryTitle" : "Австрия",
          "point" : {
            "longitude" : 16.36879539489746,
            "latitude" : 48.20253753662109
          },
          "districtTitle" : "",
          "cityId" : 2352,
          "cityTitle" : "город Вена",
          "regionTitle" : "",
          "stationId" : 9778,
          "stationTitle" : "Stadion Center, Olympiaplatz 2"
        },
        {
          "countryTitle" : "Австрия",
          "point" : {
            "longitude" : 16.36879539489746,
            "latitude" : 48.20253753662109
          },
          "districtTitle" : "",
          "cityId" : 2352,
          "cityTitle" : "город Вена",
          "regionTitle" : "",
          "stationId" : 434,
          "stationTitle" : "U-BHF ERDBERGSTR."
        },
        {
          "countryTitle" : "Австрия",
          "point" : {
            "longitude" : 16.36879539489746,
            "latitude" : 48.20253753662109
          },
          "districtTitle" : "",
          "cityId" : 2352,
          "cityTitle" : "город Вена",
          "regionTitle" : "",
          "stationId" : 874,
          "stationTitle" : "Vienna"
        }
      ]
    }

  ]
  }
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Json как парсить на Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/312660/json-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0-java)

Comment: спасибо за ссылку, но там пример попроще...Я не соображу как мне мои данные распарсить

Comment: на сайте есть поиск: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+json?sort=votes&pageSize=50

Comment: вот как можно использовать GSON http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-google-json-parse-json-to-java/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как верно подметили в комментариях, сложного в парсинге JSON-а ничего нет, и примеров на эту тему тоже достаточно. Вам нужно просто понять принцип, как работать с JSON-ом, и далее для вас не составит никакой трудности распарсить сколь угодно сложный JSON.

Лично я советую использовать библиотеку [org.json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json), с ней работать гораздо проще, чем с GSON или некоторыми другими примерами. Но этот вопрос довольно субъективен.

Конкретно на вашем примере:

```
// Допустим, в этой строке у вас находится весь ваш JSON
// Как вы его туда поместите, это уже другой вопрос
// И, надеюсь, трудностей у вас с этим не будет
String jsonString = "";

// Парсим JSON
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);

JSONArray citiesFrom = json.getJSONArray("citiesFrom");

JSONObject country = citiesFrom.getJSONObject(0);

String countryTitle = country.getString("countryTitle");

JSONArray stations = country.getJSONArray("stations");

JSONObject firstStation = stations.getJSONObject(0);

String firstStationTitle = firstStation.getString("stationTitle"); 
// International Busterminal, Edbergstarsse 200 A

// и так далее...
```

Answer (score 0):

Если честно - странный JSON с кучей дублирования.
Вы можете использовать тот же [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md) для первичного парсинга данных, затем, если судить по приведенному примеру, я бы создал два POJO класса Cities и Station которые бы создавал и заполнял данными во время парсинга. Таким образом вы бы написали свой десериализатор из JSON в Java объекты.

Comment: похоже мне надо будет записывать все это в базу данных

Comment: Отлично! Берете, например, mybatis и мапите ваши классы в БД!