# Как вытащить данные из Rest-ответа?

Tags: java, spring, rest

Нужно из запроса создать объект класса `User`

Есть класс `User`

```
public class User {

private String id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String userName;
private String plainTextPassword;
private String hashedPassword;
}
```

Есть метод в контроллере по созданию нового пользователя

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<User> update(@RequestBody User us) {

    return new ResponseEntity<User>(us, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

И есть репозиторий

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository {
    User createUser(User user) throws UserAlreadyExistsException;
}
```

С помощью Advanced REST Client делаю запрос
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема состоит в том, что не знаю как из ответа вытащить данные о пользователе и создать нового пользователя. Может есть какой-то метод типа `Scanner` для Rest-сервисов?

Comment: вы посылаете запрос на сервер, контроллер его обрабатывает и отвечает. Где именно вы хотите распарсить ответ? В браузере?

Comment: @Виктор Мне нужно, чтобы запрос вытащил все данные и создал нового пользователя и добавил его в массив, к примеру, или бд, сейчас неважно

Comment: ну так в методе контроллера у вас уже есть User us который как раз и пришел к вам на регистрацию

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Json как парсить на Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/312660/json-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0-java)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Немного переделал структуру проекта. Проблему решил с помощью `JsonNode` и `ObjectMapper`.

Репозиторий:

```
    @Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
    User save(User user);
}
```

Интерфейс UserService:

```
public interface UserService {
    User addNewUser(User user);
}
```

и его implemented класс:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public User addNewUser(User user) {
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

И сам контроллер:

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<User> update(@RequestBody JsonNode user) throws JsonProcessingException {
        User newUser = mapper.treeToValue(user, User.class);
        if (userService.addNewUser(newUser) != null) {
            return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Зачем что-то парсить? У вас уже есть готовый объект `User` в методе `update`.

Нужно его просто сохранить как-то так:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<User> update(@RequestBody User us) {
    try {
        final User newUser = UserRepository.createUser(us);
        // пользователь успешно создан
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(newUser, HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (UserAlreadyExistsException e) {
        // пользователь уже существует в БД (возвратим ошибку)
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(us, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }  
}
```