# Распарить JSON на Java

Tags: java

Простой вопрос, я на Java я нуб.
Распарить строку

```
[{"site":"bash.im","name":"bash","desc":"Цитатник Рунета"}]
```

достать name например, просто не знаю как пройти мимо `[` без названия

нужен ответ в видео кода, из моего примера

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/745094/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-json-%D0%BD%D0%B0-java/745095

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/312660/json-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-java