# Подскажите пожалуйста как мне достать объекты из JSON(при помощи JSONObject или Array) на Java? и сохранить в базу

Tags: java, json

Хочу достать объекты из Json weatherbit api , выдает ошибки о ненайденных элементах

```
String weatherappi = "weatherbit.io";
    RequestEntity<?> request = RequestEntity.get(url).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
    ResponseEntity<T> exchange = this.restTemplate.exchange(request, responseType);
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(exchange.getBody());
    //db save logic
    WeatherEntity weatherEntity = new WeatherEntity();
    JSONArray jsonArray = obj.getJSONArray("data");
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject obj1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);


        String strdate = obj1.getString("ob_time");
        Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm").parse(strdate);
        weatherEntity.setTimestamp(date.toInstant());
        weatherEntity.setCity(obj1.getString("city_name"));
        weatherEntity.setTemperature(obj1.optInt("temp"));
    }
```

Сам Json

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "rh": 45,
        "pod": "d",
        "lon": 37.61556,
        "pres": 978.78,
        "timezone": "Europe/Moscow",
        "ob_time": "2020-04-25 12:17",
        "country_code": "RU",
        "clouds": 97,
        "ts": 1587817073,
        "solar_rad": 160.383,
        "state_code": "48",
        "city_name": "Moscow",
        "wind_spd": 2.11647,
        "last_ob_time": "2020-04-25T11:30:00",
        "wind_cdir_full": "west",
        "wind_cdir": "W",
        "slp": 996.168,
        "vis": 24.135,
        "h_angle": 33.8,
        "sunset": "16:58",
        "dni": 783.56,
        "dewpt": -2.2,
        "snow": 0,
        "uv": 1.16599,
        "precip": 2.21053,
        "wind_dir": 274,
        "sunrise": "01:57",
        "ghi": 495.34,
        "dhi": 94.33,
        "aqi": 31,
        "lat": 55.75222,
        "weather": {
            "icon": "r01d",
            "code": "500",
            "description": "Light rain"
        },
        "datetime": "2020-04-25:12",
        "temp": 9.2,
        "station": "UUEE",
        "elev_angle": 38.44,
        "app_temp": 9.2
    }
],
"count": 1
```

}

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/312660/json-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0-java

Comment: благодарю , просто у меня в данном случае выходит ошибка о том что элемент с  именем не найден, сейчас разбираюсь.